# Is there any way to use python script under Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, android, python, xamarin, ironpython

I know CSharp is the language in Xamarin,but sometimes some  features of python are awesome,so I want invoke python scripts under Xamarin.
I know ironpython,so I try it.
I added some Required Assembly like: IronPython.dll,IronPython.Module,Microsoft.Scripting.dll...
Luckily,I built it successfully and it run on my Android device.
But When the code run at:

```
        ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
        ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("");
        source.Execute(scope);
```

An error occured:

```
   Microsoft.Scripting.InvalidImplementationException:
Type 'IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext' doesn't provide a suitable public constructor or its implementation is faulty:
 Could not load type 'IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext' from assembly 'IronPython, Version=2.7.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7f709c5b713576e1'.
```

So,Is there any possibility to use Python Scripts on Xamarin.Android?

Comment: So you're adding a python runtime to a xamarin runtime which interfaces with a java virtual machine for the Android SDK on an arm processor? I can't conceive of a python feature so "awesome" that I would want to ship a 30MB "Hello World" app. Learn C#.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, No.  You could conceivably port IronPython or some other Python runtime to work under Xamarin, but that would take considerable effort, and to my knowledge it hasn't been done before.

Answer (score 1):

People have asked this before, but no, the crux of Xamarin is C# (or F#) so anything else is out of scope. Am sure other people are trying to do similar things with other languages like Python, but not through Xamarin