# How to write Python script to interact with Xamarin.Forms app?

Tags: python, xamarin.forms

Can anyone advise on writing python script to interact with Xamarin.Forms app? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, But, It's not code issue. Rather, We are looking for possible ways to run Python script through Xamarin.Forms App. Really appreciate if anyone can advise on direction to fulfil the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you can not use a `python script` to interact with a `Xamarin.Forms` app. Because Xamarin.forms is based on c# and .Net. I looked up the Microsoft doc and found nothing about using the python script. Xamarin has built bindings from C#/.NET to the underlying languages and runtimes on iOS and Android.

Someone asked the same question and you can refer to this: [Is there any way to use python script under Xamarin.Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36813180/is-there-any-way-to-use-python-script-under-xamarin-android)

Comment: Hi, if you think this is a good answer, you can accept it. Thanks.